# SocketIO get information from client when disconnecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chat

I have recently been working on a simple chat app with node js. I want to send a message to everyone on it when a user leaves, saying that they have left the chat. The users name is determined by the pathname. (eg. mychatapp.com/user1 would mean that your name is user1) I am running into a problem where I cannot access the users name from the function that is called when a socket disconnects. Also I am new to node and socket, so there might have been an easy way around, but I haven't found an answer yet. Thank you to anyone who can help.

### Here is the index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

var users = [];

function removeItemOnce(arr, value) {
  var index = arr.indexOf(value);
  if (index > -1) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return arr;
}

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    // console.log();
    if (!users.includes(req.url.substring(1))) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    } else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/nametaken.html');
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', (name) => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('joined', (name) => {
        users.push(name);
        io.emit('chat message', name + " joined the chat");
    });
});

// this is SUPPOSED to be called when a user disconnects
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('left', (name) => {
        users = removeItemOnce(users, name);
        io.emit('chat message', name + " left the chat");
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

### And this is my index.html file

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding-bottom: 3rem;
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        #form {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            padding: 0.25rem;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            display: flex;
            height: 3rem;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        }

        #input {
            border: none;
            padding: 0 1rem;
            flex-grow: 1;
            border-radius: 2rem;
            margin: 0.25rem;
        }

        #input:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

        #form>button {
            background: #333;
            border: none;
            padding: 0 1rem;
            margin: 0.25rem;
            border-radius: 3px;
            outline: none;
            color: #fff;
        }

        #messages {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #messages>li {
            padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        }

        #messages>li:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #efefef;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
        <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();

  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  var input = document.getElementById('input');

  socket.emit('joined', window.location.pathname.substring(1));

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input.value) {
      socket.emit('chat message', window.location.pathname.substring(1) + ": " + input.value);
      input.value = '';
    }
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = msg;
    messages.appendChild(item);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  });
  
  // this bit here SHOULD emit the event 'left' when the tab is closed
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
    socket.emit('left', window.location.pathname.substring(1));
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to find a way to say the message in chat, but it doesn't work. Here is what I tried.

### js file:

```
// this is SUPPOSED to be called when a user disconnects
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('left', (name) => {
        users = removeItemOnce(users, name);
        io.emit('chat message', name + " left the chat");
    });
});
```

### html file inside the script tag:

```
// this bit here SHOULD emit the event 'left' when the tab is closed
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
    socket.emit('left', window.location.pathname.substring(1));
  });
```

Comment: this is unrelated, but is there a specific reason, why you made 5 different `io.on('connection...` functions, couldn't you put that into one?

Comment: i was following a tutorial, and that is what it said, plus im new to socket and i didn't know if it made a difference

Comment: you already have the disconnect listener `socket.on('disconnect', ...)` in the callback you could just access the socket object, couldn't you?

Comment: how do you get the url/pathname from the socket object though?

Comment: I tried `socket.request.url` but it just comes out as `/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nq6V2QD`